# How to add data to firestore only if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in firestore named Products.

Products JSON:

```
{ 
  Id1:
  {"product": "product1"},
  Id2:
  {"product": "product2"},
  Id3:
  {"product": "product3"},
}
```

I want to add data to it using JSON and Node Js such that I won't add any duplicate data. I'm new to NodeJS and asynchronous methods. So I want to ask, if I'm doing it correctly:

```
const data = require("./data.json");
for (var key in data) {
   var query = firestore.collection(collectionKey);
   var product = data[key]["product"];
   query.where("product", '==', product).get().then((res) => {
      if (!res.empty) {
         console.log(product + " exists");
      } else {
          firestore.collection(collectionKey).doc(key).set(data[key]).then((res) => {
             console.log(product + " successfully written!");
          .catch((error) => {
               console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
         });
      }
   });
}
```

The `console.log` only prints the last product and I don’t get to know which products already existed and which were successfully written?

EDIT:

```
node script
Console Output:

H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
H1358 exists
..
.
```

data.json contains 58 different products viz Product Ids: H1301..H1358 in sequence.

Comment: You're firing a query for every key (`Id1`, `Id2`, `Id3`), and your code should be logging something for each query. Is that not happening? Can you edit your question to show the log output?

Comment: Added the console output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I now see the problem. By the time the callback fires, the value of `key` has been updated many times - and all of these are logging the final value.

The solution here is to use a so-called [immediately invoked function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), but I find using a named function easier to read here.

```
const data = require("./data.json");
var query = firestore.collection(collectionKey);
var logIfDocExists = function(key, product) {
   query.where("product", '==', product).get().then((res) => {
      if (!res.empty) {
         console.log(product + " exists");
      } else {
          firestore.collection(collectionKey).doc(key).set(data[key]).then((res) => {
             console.log(product + " successfully written!");
          .catch((error) => {
               console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });
         });
      }
   });
};
for (var key in data) {
   var product = data[key]["product"];
   logIfDocExists(key, product);
}
```

The trick here is that `logIfDocExists(key, product)` captures the `key` as a separate value on the call stack, which then ensures you log the right value of `key` in the asynchronous callback.

---

I actually just realized another, and much simpler, way to capture the value of `key` and that is to use `let` instead of `var` in your original code. A `let` defines a block-level variable, so each iteration of the loop will have its own unique key value.

Comment: Using foreach arrow function for data, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

tl:dr; **If you want a product (`product1`, `product2`, `product3`) to be unique in the collection, you'll have to use those products as the ID for the documents.**

There unfortunately is a race conditions in your current code. Between the time when you run the query and when you actually write the document, another client might end up writing a document with the same `product` value, just as you are also writing it.

```
     Client 1                 DATABASE                  Client 2
        +                    +--------+                    +
        |  q: where p="p1"   |        |                    |
        |+------------------>|        |                    |
        |                    |        |                    |
        |  No results        |        |                    |
        |<------------------+|        |                    |
        |                    |        |   q: where p="p1"  |
        |                    |        |<------------------+|
        |                    |        |                    |
        |                    |        |   No results.      |
        |                    |        |+------------------>|
        | Create: { p: "p1"} |        |                    |
        |+------------------>|        |                    |
        |                    |        |                    |
        |      OK            |        |                    |
        |<------------------+|        |                    |
        |                    |        | Create: { p: "p1"} |
        |                    |        |<------------------+|
        |                    |        |                    |
        |                    |        | OK                 |
        |                    |        |+------------------>|
        |                    |        |                    |
        +                    +--------+                    +
```

When you know the ID of the document you are trying to create, you could [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to first get and then create that document, which ensures that no two clients can ever end up creating the document, as one of them would be forced to retry, and then fail.

But since you can't include the query itself in the transaction, there is no way for you to do the entire "find the document with this value, and then create it if not" as an atomic operation.

The only way to do this transactionally is by making the product value the key of the document. Once you do that, you don't need the query anymore, and can use a transaction to "get the document, and then create it if it doesn't exist yet".

```
     Client 1                 DATABASE                  Client 2
        +                    +--------+                    +
        | Start transaction  |        |                    |
        |+------------------>|        |                    |
        |                    |        | Start transaction  |
        |                    |        |<------------------+|
        | get document p1    |        |                    |
        |+------------------>|        |                    |
        |                    |        |                    |
        |  No result         |        |                    |
        |<------------------+|        |                    |
        |                    |        | get document p1    |
        |                    |        |<------------------+|
        |                    |        |                    |
        |                    |        |  No result         |
        |                    |        |+------------------>|
        | create document p1 |        |                    |
        |+------------------>|        |                    |
        |                    |        |                    |
        |      OK            |        |                    |
        |<------------------+|        |                    |
        |                    |        | create document p1 |
        |                    |        |<------------------+|
        |                    |        |                    |
        |                    |        |  OK                |
        |                    |        |+------------------>|
        | Commit transaction |        |                    |
        |+------------------>|        |                    |
        |                    |        |                    |
        |      OK            |        |                    |
        |<------------------+|        |                    |
        |                    |        | Commit transaction |
        |                    |        |<------------------+|
        |                    |        |                    |
        |                    |        |  Reject            |
        |                    |        |+------------------>|
        |                    |        |                    |
        +                    +--------+                    +
```

You'll also want to [use security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) on the server to reject a write that tries to recreate the same document, as a malicious user could be writing to the database without your transaction code.

---

**Update**: Doug pointed out that you actually *can* include a query in a transaction with the server-side/Admin SDKs.

Comment: Can it be done using Promises? Also there's only one client. I'm using it to populate the read only data.

Comment: Promises are a client-side mechanism to deal with the asynchronous nature of calls. This problem is related to concurrency of database access from multiple clients. I added some diagrams that hopefully explain that better.

Comment: I understood your point, but I'm saying that there's only one client who could write to the database. So race condition won't be an issue.

Comment: In that case: what is the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: Console.log only prints the last product and I don’t get to know which products already existed and which were successfully written?